# How to insert all the records in a data frame into the database in R?

Tags: r, postgresql, dataframe

I have a data frame `data_frm` which has following columns:

```
emp_id | emp_sal | emp_bonus | emp_desig_level
       |         |           |    
       |         |           |
```

And I want to insert all the records present in this data frame into the database table `tab1`.I executed this query but I got an error:

```
for(record in data_frm)
    {   
    write_sql <- paste("Insert into tab1 (emp_id,emp_sal,emp_bonus,emp_desig_level) values (",data_frm[,"emp_id"],",",data_frm[,"emp_sal"],",",data_frm[,"emp_bonus"],",",data_frm[,"emp_desig_level"],")",sep="") 
    r <- dbSendQuery(r,write_sql)   
    }
```

I get error as:

```
Error in data_frm[, "emp_id"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How do I insert all the records from the data frame into database?

**NOTE:** I want to insert all the records of the data frame using `insert` statement.

Comment: Depending on your Database there probably is a package for this like `RMySQL` for MySQL. There it is `dbWriteTable`. What Database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql. Is there no way where I can use normal `insert` statement to write data frame records?

Comment: Actually, @Floo0, RDBI, implemented by RMySQL, RJDBC, RPgSQL, etc. calls for dbWriteTable

Answer (score 2):

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "RESULTS", results2000, append = T) # to protect current values
dbWriteTable(conn, "RESULTS", results2000, append = F) # to overwrite values
```

From the [RDBI homepage](http://rdbi.sourceforge.net/) at sourceforge. Hope that helps...

Comment: Is there any where I can use normal `insert` statement to write data frame records?

Comment: Due to some constraints I don't want to use `dbWriteTable` and want to use traditional `insert` statement way only.

Comment: Your quotes are being misinterpreted by R. Use [RDBI prepared statements](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/DBI.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you need to put:

```
data_frm[record,"column_name"]
```

Other wise your loop is trying to insert the entire column instead of just the particular record.

```
for(record in data_frm)
    {   
    write_sql <- paste("Insert into tab1 (emp_id,emp_sal,emp_bonus,emp_desig_level) values (",data_frm[record,"emp_id"],",",data_frm[record,"emp_sal"],",",data_frm[record,"emp_bonus"],",",data_frm[record,"emp_desig_level"],")",sep="") 
    r <- dbSendQuery(r,write_sql)   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64121048/12389926)

Copied one more time:

Recently I had similar issue.

**Problem description**: MS Server data base **with scheme**. The task is to save an R data.frame object to a predefined data base table **without dropping** it.

**Problems I faced**:

- Some packages functions does not support schemes or require github development version installation
- You can save data.frame only after **drop** (delete table) operation (I needed just "clear table" operation)

**How I solved the issue**

- Using simple **RODBC::sqlQuery**, writing a data.frame row by row.
- The solution (couple of functions) is available [here](https://github.com/PankoAliaksandr/R/wiki/Write%5CSave-R-data-frame-to-Data-Base-Table) or [here](https://github.com/PankoAliaksandr/R/blob/master/WriteDFtoDB.R)